# Printing in Javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a question that seems basic but i can't seem to figure it out.

Write a program that takes the value of a variable called “input” (declared as   any whole number at the top of your program) and outputs a square made of asterisks (*) as large as the number (input). For example, if the “input” is  declared with the value 5, your program would display a square made of 25 asterisks(*) – ie ; 5 asterisks (*) high, by 5 asterisks (*) long.

The code i've come up with so far is below. I don't really understand how to make a string continuously print. If i did star = i then it turns into numbers and will print the numbers. So how do i make it so they connect? I also can't figure out where i should put the new line. console.log(star "\n"); gives me an error. Please help :)

```js
  var input = 2;
    var star = "*";
    var i = 0;

    do { 
    console.log(star);
    i++;

    } while (i < input);
```

Comment: Hint: you don't want to print every asterisk individually, you want to print every line of asterisks. That means you'll need to build the line of asterisks first and then `console.log()` it.

Comment: There are any number of ways this could be done. Right now you only have printing of a single line (well, you don't, but you meant to), whereas you need to print both columns and rows. I'd consider building a string of the required number of asterisks, then printing the correct number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.repeat()` (ES6 only) along with `\r\n` to add new line

```js
var input = 5,
    star = "*",
    str = [],
    i = 0;

do {
   str.push( Array(input).join(star) ); // use array(length).join
   i++;
} while (i < input);

str = str.join("\r\n"); // add breaklines
console.log(str);
```

Comment: i kinda see where i was going wrong now, only thing is using repeat might be too advanced for where i'm at. But this helps thank you :)

Comment: @GianNobilione, I downgraded a bit

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` Will output a single line to the console containing whatever you pass it as an argument. You are trying to print a line of *n* asterisks *n* times.

The first step you should take is constructing the string of asterisks. You can concatenate a string to another with the `+` operator:

```
var input = 2;
var star = "*";
var line = "";

for(var i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    line = line + star;
}
```

Once you have constructed `line` you can then print it `n` times:

```
for(var i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    console.log(line);
}
```

Comment: this is quite helpful. Now i just gotta add the \n so it makes it into a box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `repeat`-function to print a character multiple times.

```js
 var input = 2;
    var star = "*";
    var i = 0;

    while(i++ < input){
      console.log(star.repeat(input));
    }
```

This repeats the `*` character `input` times in `input` lines.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You could create an empty array and then create a loop ending at your wanted number of asterisks after which you will join all the members of the array together. (Writing the code here wouldn't help you much since you mentioned it's an homework).

Comment: Thanks for the hint :) I actually was looking for hints/help opposed to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this in two ways. If we call your input value n, then we can log either n strings each consisting of n stars, or we can log a single string, containing (n * n) stars, with line breaks after every nth star.

Below is an example of a function that could do this task.

```
function stars (input) {
  var output = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < input; j++) {
      output += '*'
    }
    output += '\n'
  }
  return output
}
```